# If NSNetService name method is deprecated in iOS 7.x, how do I find the name of the service?

Tags: nsnetservice, nsnetservicebrowser

The current documentation for NSNetService states that the 'name' is deprecated after iOS 6.1

Since that is the case, how do I find the name of a service which has been discovered with an NSNetServiceBrowser?

NSNetServiceBrowser calls the delegate method didFindService: with an NSNetService object. How do I correctly get the service name of the service it found?

Answer (score 0):

`name` has turned into a property and is not deprecated as of iOS 7.